# Base Class in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm new to .NET Core having been in standard ASP.NET for a long time.

I'm really struggling with creating a base class for all of my models as they all share a couple of fields.

Basically in each table I have the following columns:

```
Id
CreatedByUserID
CreationDateTime
UpdatedByUserID
UpdatedDateTime
DeletedByUserID
DeletionDateTime
IsDeleted
```

My base entity code:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdateByUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid DeletedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User? CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User? DeletedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User? UpdateByUser { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        CreatedByUserId = Guid.Empty;
        UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        UpdateByUserId = Guid.Empty;
        DeletedDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        DeletedByUserId = Guid.Empty;
        IsDeleted = false;
    }
}
```

Part of my user code:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public User()
    {
        BaseCreatedByUsers = new HashSet<BaseEntity>();
        BaseDeletedByUsers = new HashSet<BaseEntity>();
        BaseUpdateByUsers = new HashSet<BaseEntity>();
    }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public int IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public String DisplayName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdateByUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeletedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid DeletedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BaseEntity> BaseCreatedByUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BaseEntity> BaseDeletedByUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BaseEntity> BaseUpdateByUsers { get; set; }
}
```

If I do not include base entity in the `ApplicationDbContext` file, then I get the error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'User.BaseCreatedByUsers' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

But if I do include it in `ApplicationDbContext`:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseEntity>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.CreatedByUser)
                .WithMany(p => p.BaseCreatedByUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedByUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Base_User");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.DeletedByUser)
                .WithMany(p => p.BaseDeletedByUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeletedByUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Base_User2");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.UpdateByUser)
                .WithMany(p => p.BaseUpdateByUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UpdateByUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Base_User1");
        });
```

Then I get this error:

> Both 'ReceivingSheetTemplateDetail' and 'BaseEntity' are mapped to the table 'BaseEntity'. All the entity types in a hierarchy that don't have a discriminator must be mapped to different tables.

In this case `ReceivingSheetTemplateDetail` is using the base entity class.

My goal in all of this is just to take out the hassle of adding these fields to every model and to make saving easier as I can overwrite on class instead of having to do it for each.

I know I'm missing something so I would appreciate any assistance :)

Comment: Why an abstract base class? Can't you just define an `IBaseEntity` **interface** which all your entity classes implement (and that contains all those fields in question) ?

Comment: Just leave BaseEntity out of your DbContext and make all Navigation Properties concrete subtypes.  Some inheritance patterns don’t translate well to a database.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you so much. Will give that a go. From what I've seen that should sort it,

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I've tried all I can but I think because I am still learning core I'm making a few mistakes. Also I did do a Database first approach with this one

Comment: @marc_s Can I still use the Interface to create a Virtual ICollection on the Users class?  and a virtual user on the Interface? On some index pages i show who the creted by user was by reference